# StartActivity from Application closes app

Tags: android, oncreate, start-activity, android-application-class

I've got a class that extends the Application, and from there, on shake detection, it should open up an activity. However, for a specific Activity it closes the app instead. There are NO crashes or errors in the logs which is making this really hard to debug...

Code is as follows to start the activity:

```
                int currentViewingMemberId = CommonFunctions.get_CURRENT_VIEWING_MEMBER_ID(this);
                Bitmap b = takeScreenshot();
                Intent contactAndReportIntent = ReportIssueActivity.getIntentForActivity(getApplicationContext(), true, null, b, currentViewingMemberId);
                contactAndReportIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(contactAndReportIntent);

                mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                hasAccelerometerSensorBeenRegistered = false;
```

getIntentForActivity() method is as follows:

```
public static Intent getIntentForActivity(Context context, boolean isFromShake, String helpTip, Bitmap screenshot, int currentViewingMemberId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReportIssueActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FROM_SHAKE, isFromShake);
        if (helpTip == null) {
            helpTip = "";
        }
        if (screenshot != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            intent.putExtra(SCREENSHOT_IMAGE, byteArray);
        }
        intent.putExtra(HELP_TIP, helpTip);
        intent.putExtra(CURRENT_VIEWING_MEMBER_ID, currentViewingMemberId);
        return intent;
    }
```

takeScreenshot() captures the current window and returns a Bitmap successfully, but the Activity onCreate() is not even called.

Any ideas would help, thanks! :)

Comment: What's there inside the function : getIntentForActivity() ?

Comment: @davya301, put your code in try block and print stacktrace. Then check in logcat for Verbose. There might any exception.

Comment: hi @jaimin, i've updated my question with the intentforactivity method. i've also tried surrounding everything in try/catches, but no errors are thrown

Comment: what do you mean by "specific activity" ?

Comment: i meant it only ever seemed to happen in one scenario, but i've found the issue now

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i was getting a TransactionTooLargeException when trying to return my activity Intent. 
Swapping:

```
 screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

for:

```
 screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
```

fixed it as it reduced the screenshot image size to below the allowed amount.